# Can I see a map of the current planet?

Tags: starbound

I've found myself lost several times on a planet and I see no kind of map in the game.
Is there any way at all to see a map of the current planet?

Comment: Speculations about future features in games or developers intent are offtopic.

Comment: Starbound is currently in private beta, thus its questions are on-topic.

Comment: This question isn't asking about intent - it's asking about the current state of the game so is perfectly on topic. (Before the question got edited by another user) To answer this question wouldn't require that map functionality is built into the game, it would be perfectly valid to post a community made map.

Comment: It's on-topic enough to be answerable, including why part of it is off-topic.  Though I'm sure the asker would love to hear about any community mods that may have been made to implement a map system.  I have no doubt that there's probably one or two already in the works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maps are not currently in the game.  Whether or not there will be one in the future is entirely unknown, and not covered by the scope of Stack Exchange questions, but as for whether or not they exist currently, they do not.

If you want to find out about planned updates, I'd suggest going to the [Chucklefish Forums](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php), where discussion about Starbound is very active and future updates are being discussed right now.

Comment: Stated in the blog post ["The future of starbound"](http://playstarbound.com/the-future-of-starbound/) as a possible feature: Mini-Map: Rotating circular map showing highlights only such as the location of friendly players, spawn points–but no major details. For the details you’d use a mapping item to create a map as you travel.

Comment: @JérémieBertrand Interesting...perhaps we can offer an updated answer if this map does make it into the game.

Comment: As of 1.0 stable there still does not appear to be an in game map. Shame, because it would be really handy.

Comment: Lack of map of any kind really hurts the gameplay. I can't pick where I teleport to when I respawn -- even if I have a nice settlement built? Boo.

Comment: you can pick where to teleport by putting down flags